# Xamarin Android 'App' Has Stopped (Nougat)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

During the lifetime of the application we get the message 'App' Has Stopped. All methods currently have the try and catch clause, however we are unable to catch this unhandled exception. 
We have tried everything and could not find the culprit for this. We have managed to get the android log of the application so could someone please give as an idea of what the issue might be?

The log:

```
06-20 09:23:42.711 12647 12647 F libc    : Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 12647 (mSales.mSales)
06-20 09:23:42.794 12878 12878 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
06-20 09:23:42.794 12878 12878 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'samsung/gts28ltexx/gts28lte:7.0/NRD90M/T715XXU2CQCL:user/release-keys'
06-20 09:23:42.794 12878 12878 F DEBUG   : Revision: '9'
06-20 09:23:42.794 12878 12878 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm'
06-20 09:23:42.794 12878 12878 F DEBUG   : pid: 12647, tid: 12647, name: mSales.mSales  >>> mSales.mSales <<<
06-20 09:23:42.795 12878 12878 F DEBUG   : signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
06-20 09:23:42.799 12878 12878 F DEBUG   : Abort message: 'art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128] JNI ERROR (app bug): weak global reference table overflow (max=51200)'
06-20 09:23:42.800 12878 12878 F DEBUG   :     r0 00000000  r1 00003167  r2 00000006  r3 00000008
06-20 09:23:42.800 12878 12878 F DEBUG   :     r4 a778558c  r5 00000006  r6 a7785534  r7 0000010c
06-20 09:23:42.800 12878 12878 F DEBUG   :     r8 a447d464  r9 00000000  sl bed88338  fp a4469ed4
06-20 09:23:42.800 12878 12878 F DEBUG   :     ip 00000002  sp bed88268  lr a5f8b4b7  pc a5f8dd20  cpsr 600f0010
06-20 09:23:42.819 12878 12878 F DEBUG   : 
06-20 09:23:42.819 12878 12878 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
06-20 09:23:42.819 12878 12878 F DEBUG   :     #00 pc 0004ad20  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
06-20 09:23:42.819 12878 12878 F DEBUG   :     #01 pc 000484b3  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+34)
06-20 09:23:42.819 12878 12878 F DEBUG   :     #02 pc 0001dd89  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
06-20 09:23:42.819 12878 12878 F DEBUG   :     #03 pc 00019511  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+34)
06-20 09:23:42.819 12878 12878 F DEBUG   :     #04 pc 00017150  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
06-20 09:23:42.819 12878 12878 F DEBUG   :     #05 pc 0031b3bd  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEv+252)
06-20 09:23:42.819 12878 12878 F DEBUG   :     #06 pc 000b4ccb  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10LogMessageD2Ev+866)
06-20 09:23:42.819 12878 12878 F DEBUG   :     #07 pc 001bd093  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art22IndirectReferenceTable3AddEjPNS_6mirror6ObjectE+194)
06-20 09:23:42.819 12878 12878 F DEBUG   :     #08 pc 0023a72f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt16AddWeakGlobalRefEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_6mirror6ObjectE+46)
06-20 09:23:42.819 12878 12878 F DEBUG   :     #09 pc 0027ff63  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art3JNI16NewWeakGlobalRefEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobject+418)
06-20 09:23:42.819 12878 12878 F DEBUG   :     #10 pc 0000b5cf  /data/app/mSales.mSales-1/lib/arm/libmonodroid.so
06-20 09:23:42.819 12878 12878 F DEBUG   :     #11 pc 00009e71  /data/app/mSales.mSales-1/lib/arm/libmonodroid.so
06-20 09:23:42.819 12878 12878 F DEBUG   :     #12 pc 002326c8  /data/app/mSales.mSales-1/lib/arm/libmonosgen-2.0.so
06-20 09:38:19.287 15440 15440 F libc    : Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 15440 (mSales.mSales)
06-20 09:38:19.369 15630 15630 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
06-20 09:38:19.369 15630 15630 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'samsung/gts28ltexx/gts28lte:7.0/NRD90M/T715XXU2CQCL:user/release-keys'
06-20 09:38:19.369 15630 15630 F DEBUG   : Revision: '9'
06-20 09:38:19.369 15630 15630 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm'
06-20 09:38:19.370 15630 15630 F DEBUG   : pid: 15440, tid: 15440, name: mSales.mSales  >>> mSales.mSales <<<
06-20 09:38:19.370 15630 15630 F DEBUG   : signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
06-20 09:38:19.375 15630 15630 F DEBUG   : Abort message: 'art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128] JNI ERROR (app bug): weak global reference table overflow (max=51200)'
06-20 09:38:19.375 15630 15630 F DEBUG   :     r0 00000000  r1 00003c50  r2 00000006  r3 00000008
06-20 09:38:19.375 15630 15630 F DEBUG   :     r4 a778558c  r5 00000006  r6 a7785534  r7 0000010c
06-20 09:38:19.375 15630 15630 F DEBUG   :     r8 a447d464  r9 00000000  sl bed88c00  fp a4469ed4
06-20 09:38:19.375 15630 15630 F DEBUG   :     ip 00000002  sp bed88b30  lr a5f8b4b7  pc a5f8dd20  cpsr 600f0010
06-20 09:38:19.394 15630 15630 F DEBUG   : 
06-20 09:38:19.394 15630 15630 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
06-20 09:38:19.394 15630 15630 F DEBUG   :     #00 pc 0004ad20  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
06-20 09:38:19.394 15630 15630 F DEBUG   :     #01 pc 000484b3  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+34)
06-20 09:38:19.394 15630 15630 F DEBUG   :     #02 pc 0001dd89  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
06-20 09:38:19.394 15630 15630 F DEBUG   :     #03 pc 00019511  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+34)
06-20 09:38:19.395 15630 15630 F DEBUG   :     #04 pc 00017150  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
06-20 09:38:19.395 15630 15630 F DEBUG   :     #05 pc 0031b3bd  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEv+252)
06-20 09:38:19.395 15630 15630 F DEBUG   :     #06 pc 000b4ccb  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10LogMessageD2Ev+866)
06-20 09:38:19.395 15630 15630 F DEBUG   :     #07 pc 001bd093  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art22IndirectReferenceTable3AddEjPNS_6mirror6ObjectE+194)
06-20 09:38:19.395 15630 15630 F DEBUG   :     #08 pc 0023a72f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt16AddWeakGlobalRefEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_6mirror6ObjectE+46)
06-20 09:38:19.395 15630 15630 F DEBUG   :     #09 pc 0027ff63  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art3JNI16NewWeakGlobalRefEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobject+418)
06-20 09:38:19.395 15630 15630 F DEBUG   :     #10 pc 0000b5cf  /data/app/mSales.mSales-1/lib/arm/libmonodroid.so
06-20 09:38:19.395 15630 15630 F DEBUG   :     #11 pc 00009e71  /data/app/mSales.mSales-1/lib/arm/libmonodroid.so
06-20 09:38:19.395 15630 15630 F DEBUG   :     #12 pc 002326c8  /data/app/mSales.mSales-1/lib/arm/libmonosgen-2.0.so
06-20 09:58:55.045 17536 17536 F libc    : Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 17536 (mSales.mSales)
06-20 09:58:55.120 17740 17740 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
06-20 09:58:55.120 17740 17740 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'samsung/gts28ltexx/gts28lte:7.0/NRD90M/T715XXU2CQCL:user/release-keys'
06-20 09:58:55.120 17740 17740 F DEBUG   : Revision: '9'
06-20 09:58:55.120 17740 17740 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm'
06-20 09:58:55.120 17740 17740 F DEBUG   : pid: 17536, tid: 17536, name: mSales.mSales  >>> mSales.mSales <<<
06-20 09:58:55.120 17740 17740 F DEBUG   : signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
06-20 09:58:55.124 17740 17740 F DEBUG   : Abort message: 'art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128] JNI ERROR (app bug): weak global reference table overflow (max=51200)'
06-20 09:58:55.124 17740 17740 F DEBUG   :     r0 00000000  r1 00004480  r2 00000006  r3 00000008
06-20 09:58:55.124 17740 17740 F DEBUG   :     r4 a778558c  r5 00000006  r6 a7785534  r7 0000010c
06-20 09:58:55.124 17740 17740 F DEBUG   :     r8 a447d464  r9 00000000  sl bed89018  fp a4469ed4
06-20 09:58:55.125 17740 17740 F DEBUG   :     ip 00000002  sp bed88f48  lr a5f8b4b7  pc a5f8dd20  cpsr 600f0010
06-20 09:58:55.143 17740 17740 F DEBUG   : 
06-20 09:58:55.143 17740 17740 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
06-20 09:58:55.143 17740 17740 F DEBUG   :     #00 pc 0004ad20  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
06-20 09:58:55.143 17740 17740 F DEBUG   :     #01 pc 000484b3  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+34)
06-20 09:58:55.143 17740 17740 F DEBUG   :     #02 pc 0001dd89  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
06-20 09:58:55.143 17740 17740 F DEBUG   :     #03 pc 00019511  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+34)
06-20 09:58:55.143 17740 17740 F DEBUG   :     #04 pc 00017150  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
06-20 09:58:55.143 17740 17740 F DEBUG   :     #05 pc 0031b3bd  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEv+252)
06-20 09:58:55.143 17740 17740 F DEBUG   :     #06 pc 000b4ccb  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10LogMessageD2Ev+866)
06-20 09:58:55.143 17740 17740 F DEBUG   :     #07 pc 001bd093  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art22IndirectReferenceTable3AddEjPNS_6mirror6ObjectE+194)
06-20 09:58:55.143 17740 17740 F DEBUG   :     #08 pc 0023a72f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt16AddWeakGlobalRefEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_6mirror6ObjectE+46)
06-20 09:58:55.143 17740 17740 F DEBUG   :     #09 pc 0027ff63  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art3JNI16NewWeakGlobalRefEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobject+418)
06-20 09:58:55.143 17740 17740 F DEBUG   :     #10 pc 0000b5cf  /data/app/mSales.mSales-1/lib/arm/libmonodroid.so
06-20 09:58:55.143 17740 17740 F DEBUG   :     #11 pc 00009e71  /data/app/mSales.mSales-1/lib/arm/libmonodroid.so
06-20 09:58:55.143 17740 17740 F DEBUG   :     #12 pc 002326c8  /data/app/mSales.mSales-1/lib/arm/libmonosgen-2.0.so
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key here is 'weak global reference table overflow (max=51200)'.  Basically, you are keeping a reference to something that's returned from a JNI call and never releasing it.

The best thing to do is to go through where ever you make JNI calls and check that you remove the references once you are done with them.

If you are not making JNI calls, then it's also likely that you are keeping references around that you no longer need. Watch out for nested references, these never get garbage collected and will build up over the life of the application until you run into an Operating System level exception.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help we will look into it. Can you please give as an example of a JNI call that could possibly cause this? Also by nested references do you mean references from nested classes?

Comment: Anything that stores a value from a JNI, but, if you need to ask that, you are most likely not making a native call in any case.

With nested references, I mean classes that keep references to classes that, in turn, keep references.  The garbage collector can then never free them, because the whole chain is keeping links to each other.